# unable to execute hibernate query statement?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

while using this HQL "from Student s where s.address=:x and s.name=:n" why this org.hibernate.QueryException is coming. Can someone please help me.

The alias property is not working. if I remove the variable s then it works fine.
If I write this code

```
String Query = "from Student s where s.address=:x and s.name=:n";
Query q = s.createQuery(Query);
q.setParameter("x", "Mumbi");
    q.setParameter("n", "vikash");
    List<Student> list = q.list();
    for (Student stu : list) {
        System.out.println(stu.getId() + " : " + stu.getAddress() + " : " + stu.getCerti() + " : " + 
        stu.getName());
    }
```

It works fine.
but while using alias(Student s where s.address=:a and s.name=:n;)
an exception is coming can someone please help me out from this problem.

Comment: Please include the definition of the `Student` class, specifically include all fields in that class.

Comment: Please post the stack trace (all the exceptions with their error messages) that you're seeing when you execute it, and the code of the `Student` class.